# Available Protein sequence alignment dataset and HMM model

Tags: dna, proteins, sequence-analysis, sequence-alignment, data

I am new to biology and I find my algorithm may be used in the Protein sequence alignment, since it is a henced HMM model. I find that people use HMM to generate noisy copies of the consensus sequence of different lengths. There is a figure show the process: 
[image]

It seems Professor Richard Durbin may release some dataset. But how can I find available datasets? I lost in the bio-vocabulary and fail to find datasets. Also I am wondering whether or not this topic is very minor in this community?

Update: 
Since I may abuse the vocabulary, it may be better to post the original word I read.
[image]

Comment: It may be helpful to post this on bioinformatics.stackexchange.com, which is specifically focused towards bioinformatics questions such as this. Additionally, when you say "dataset", what do you mean? Are you talking about sequence alignments, HMM parameterizations, profile HMMs, or consensus sequences? I would guess sequence alignments, but those are _extremely_ common and fairly trivial to generate so it seems unlikely.

Comment: @MaximilianPress Thanks for your comment. Maybe it is a good place to post it. I add more details. When it comes to the dataset, I mean we need some data to train the HMM model and learn the model parameter. I guess the dataset is some real sequence instead of generated artificially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNA and protein sequences (both are reasonable to use in HMMs) are available at a variety of sources, such as [EMBL](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/services/proteins), [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/), and [others](https://www.hsls.pitt.edu/obrc/index.php?page=general_similarity_search_alignment).

To input them into a model such as an HMM which draws on comparisons between different sequences, you will most likely need to produce a *sequence alignment*, which is a data format in which the sequences are processed into a matrix (generally not delimited in any way but rather where each column is a single string character) where columns or *positions* of the matrix are considered to occupy the same position in the sequence. These positions can be "gaps", represented usually by "-". The diagram at the top of the Durbin figure is such an alignment.

There are many many many tools for aligning sequences, both protein and DNA (DNA is a "nucleotide"; RNA is also a "nucleotide" sequence, but DNA is much more common to align in most applications).

Some of the common tools for generating multiple sequence alignments are [ClustalO](http://www.clustal.org/omega/) and [MAFFT](https://mafft.cbrc.jp/alignment/software/). Notably, you are not as interested (I think) in tools such as BLAST which are mostly about searching single sequences against databases using local alignment, rather than for generating multiple sequence alignments for input to other programs.

I believe that with some searching you can find existing multiple sequence alignment databases. People do not usually save them and put them in databases or repositories because usually which data you use is very specific to the problem that you are interested in, and they are quite simple to generate. Most of the databases are likely to be quite old for this reason; I found [one such old database](ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/embl/align) (described [here](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/18/5/763/199925)) with a bit of googling.